# Is RBT always full?

Tags: algorithm, graph, red-black-tree

As I understand, binary trees do not have to be full. However, it seems that RBTs have to be full (sometimes children are NIL). Is that true, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The path from the root node to all leaf nodes of any given red-black tree all have the same number of black nodes. In that sense I suppose you could say that red-black trees are always 'full' but I don't see that being a very useful definition.

The general idea of the red-black algorithm is to constrain the actual maximum difference in total height of leaf nodes (not just black height) between the leaf node with the shortest total path and the leaf node with the longest total path. If you use that as your basis then a RB tree is 'full' if all leaf nodes have the same total height (just as a regular binary tree is full if all leaves are at the same depth) and an RB tree does not have to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

No. Red Black Trees are not always full. In fact that's a seldom event. You can learn more about it by reading the book Introduction to Algorithms (Cormen, page 308), 3rd Edition (it has some figures illustrating the answer at page 310, i am not showing them because copyright).